# Adaptive Cards in Carousel Layout in Facebook Messenger using Bot Framework

Tags: .net, facebook, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I was trying to use Adaptive Cards for my chatbot using Bot Framework, to use in FB Messenger, with a carousel layout. But apparently FB doesn't support Adaptive Cards, and renders them into an image + buttons. So what I wanted to know, as a way to go around it, was if it's possible to manually render the adaptive cards Json code into images, and use those images for the layout.

I've tried simply adding the cards as they were and setting the layout, but Facebook simply lists them, not in carousel.

I'm building with .NET.

Comment: As a workaround, you may use HeroCard for example

Comment: I thought about that, but Hero Card allows for a maximum of 80 characters in text, and I needed alot more. That was why I wanted to render the json from the adaptive card, try and use that generated image as the image of the Hero Card.

Comment: You can check the actual support status here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status    It seems that is not supported yet. I will investigate if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You have more flexibility if you use the facebook messenger native templates, you can find more info about them [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/templates), but you must consider that if you are looking for a way to have more characters in your card's title & subtitle that won't be possible because of facebook's restrictions which you may find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/template/generic/) at the bottom of the page