# Whether Input form Adaptive card is supported by native template of Facebook using bot framework node.js v4

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

Input form adaptive card is supported in WebChat using Bot framework (node.js). The samples can be viewed here in this [link](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/). I want to use the same Input form adaptive card in Facebook. Is there any ways through which we can do it? Here in this link it is described about the adaptive cards in carousel layout [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235051/adaptive-cards-in-carousel-layout-in-facebook-messenger-using-bot-framework/49241483#49241483) and point out that native template of Facebook can be used for adaptive card. So, can the Input form adaptive card also be done using the native templates of Facebook. Have anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Messenger renders AdaptiveCards as images and forwards the image to the chat. Consequently, input fields are not supported in the Facebook channel. Also, I don't believe Facebook's templates have input fields.

An alternative option to gather information from the user is to use Facebook's [WebView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview#display).

Hope this helps.